# has many for model in subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model, that is located in models/statistics(Model1) and a model in models(Model2)
How do i correctly connect Model1 in Model2 via has_many?
I have tried has_many :statistics_model1s, but that didn't work

Comment: Could you explain your problem a little bit better? You could add snippets of the models and the exact model names and path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this question : [How to do has_many with a model that is in a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405177/how-to-do-has-many-with-a-model-that-is-in-a-namespace).
This might resolve your problem ;)